# How to use regex with bind attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using remote validation with complex type. As the name of my field can be something like name="user.name", I need to use the [BindAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) like that

```
public JsonResult ValidName[Bind(Prefix="user.name")]string name){ ... }
```

or the binding will not work.

The problem is that there will be many different name that end with `"user.name"` like `"employee.user.name"` or `"manager.user.name"`.

So, is it possible to bind all field where the name end with `"user.name"` to `string name` in the method declaration?

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the use of `Prefix`. Its for identifying what a complex property name (dot notation) **starts with**, not ends with. If for example you had a view model `MyModel` with a complex property `Organisation` with a complex property `Address` with a property `City` then in you view, you might have

```
@model MyModel
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Organisation.Address.City)
```

would render the following html

```
<input name="Organisation.Address.City" ...... />
```

If you only wanted to post back the value of `City` then you would use

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Prefix="Organisation.Address")] string city)
```

Similarly if you only wanted to post back all values of `Address`, it would be

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Prefix="Organisation")] Address address)
{
  string city = address.City;
```

So in your case above, you would need both

```
public JsonResult ValidName[Bind(Prefix="employee.user")] string name)
```

and

```
public JsonResult ValidName[Bind(Prefix="manager.user")] string name)
```

Comment: Well, it feels like it would be great to have suffix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Request.QueryString` to manually bind the parameter that you want in the controller method. Here is a quick code to bind the first parameter that end with the specified suffix

```
private bool EndWith(string input, string end)
{
    string pattern = @"" + end + @"$";
    Regex rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return rx.Match(input).Success;
}

private string bindSuffix(string suffix)
{
    string result = null;

    foreach (var key in Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
    {
        if (EndWith(key, suffix))
        {
            result = Request.QueryString[key];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

//Then use it like that
public JsonResult ValidName()
{
    string name = bindSuffix("user.name");
    ...
}
```